# How can I keep my target element for my bootstrap-tour center of the screen instead of the current step?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-tour

For example. Here is a screenshot of the current webpage with half of the target element offscreen.

[image]

In this instance, the current step in the tour is centered on screen, but is there a way I could show both on the screen (my steps and my target element i.e. content), without cutting out my content?

```
   var tour = new Tour({
        storage: false
   });

   tour.addSteps([{
      element: "#TransferInfo",
      placement: "bottom",
      title: "Welcome to our landing page!",
      content: "Here is some basic information about this path to this degree program.",
  //    backdrop: true,
      backdropPadding: {
          left: -370,
          right: -370,
          bottom: 20
      },
    },
    {
      element: "#GenEdTable",
      placement: "bottom",
      title: "General Education Categories",
      content: "By clicking on these headers, you will see the equivalencies for the respective courses.  Complete one course per General Education category to get fulfill the university's General Education requirements.",
    //  backdrop: true,
      backdropPadding: {
          left: -370,
          right: -370,
          bottom: 40,
          top: 40
      },
    },
    {
      element: "#MajorTable",
      placement: "bottom",
      title: "Major Courses",
      content: "These give you equivalencies for courses you can take at your community college that directly go toward your major.",
  //    backdrop: true,
      backdropPadding: {
          left: -370,
          right: -370,
          bottom: 40,
          top: 40
      },
    }
  ]);

  tour.init();
  tour.start();
```

Three drop down forms are clicked, and then the user receives queried info from the database.  So, the tour starts immediately after the last and final click.

Comment: could you provide your current codes and we can start from there

Comment: Yes, just updated by adding some of the code I used for this implementation.  Please let me know if you'd need anything else, and thanks in advance!